# Django PostgreSQL database table design, foreign keys, 1 to many

Tags: django, postgresql, database-design

I have 4 tables in my database. The image below shows the rows and columns with the name of the table enclosed in a red box. 4 tables total. Am I going about the relationship design correctly? This is a test project and I am strongly assuming that I will use a JOIN to get the entire set of data on one table. I want to start this very correctly.

A beginner question but is it normal that the publisher table, for example, has 4 rows with Nintendo?

I am using Django 1.7 along with PostgreSQL 9.3. I aim to keep simple with room to grow.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you've got the relations back-to-front here...

You have `game_id` (i.e. a ForeignKey relation) on each of `publisher`, `developer` and `platform` models... but that means each of those entities can only be related to a *single* game. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want.

You need it the other way around... instead put three foreign keys onto the `game` model, one each for `publisher`, `developer` and `platform`.

A `ForeignKey` is what's called a [**many-to-one** relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/). In this example I think what you want is for 'many' games to be related to 'one' publisher. Same for developer and platform.

> is it normal that the publisher table, for example, has 4 rows with Nintendo?

No, that's is an example of why you have it backwards. You should only have a single row for each publisher.

Comment: I want to make it clear that a single game can have more than one publisher, can have more than one developer, and have more than one platform. Would your resolution solve that?

Comment: in that case you need `ManyToMany` fields instead of `ForeignKey` on the `Game` model... you still only want a single row for each publisher in the publisher table etc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: So a ManyToMany on Game model only? No foreign keys anymore anywhere? hmm... Many games can have many publishers for example. I say CAN HAVE. Most games only have 1 publisher and 1 developer. I need this to allow all exceptions.

Comment: yes, the ManyToMany relation allows multiple but can have none or one.  (read the docs to understand how this works, the underlying implementation of a ManyToMany field is actually an extra table like `gamepublisher` which contains two fields, a foreign key to each of `game` and `publisher`... but normally this detail is hidden and you don't need to interact with the 'through table' directly)

Comment: the main idea is that the `game` table contains a single row for each game, the `publisher` table has a single row for each publisher etc... this is called a ['normalised' db schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)... from there you should map out conceptually what type of relation you need between each model (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many) and that will dictate what type of fields go on which model

Answer (score 1):

yes you are correct in saying that something is wrong.

First of all those screen shots are hard to follow, for this simple example they could work but that is not the right tool, pick up pen and paper and sketch some relational diagrams and think about what are the entities involved in the schema and what are their relations, for example you know you have publishers, and they can publish games, so in this restricted example you have 2 entities, `game` and `publisher`, and a relation `publish` among them (in this case you can place a fk on game if you have a single publisher for a game, or create an intermediary relation for a many to many case). The same point can be made for platform and games, why are you placing an fk to game there, what will happen if the game with id 2 will be published for nintendo 64 ? You are making the exact same mistake in all the entities.

Pick up any book about database design basics, maybe it will help in reasoning about your context and future problems.